# Is it possible to execute an IHttpModule only for MVC / Controller Action requests?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, nhibernate, iis, httphandler

I have an HttpModule for my NHibernate Session Management.

The problem is that when pictures are loaded each request will invoke my HttpModule and creates a new ISession, which is a kind of stupid.

It would be nice to configure the HttpModule so that it is only invoked for MVC requests. Or otherwise the HttpModule should not invoked by requests for images, css, js and so on.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly the overhead of creating a new session is not very big - it doesn't necessarily connect to the database.

Secondly, you can open and close the session using a Filter instead of a Module in MVC if you only want it for MVC requests

Comment: Do you have an example where a filter is used? Is it possible to use your filter approach and having more than one controller involved in one webrequest?

Comment: If you mean something like this: http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2010/07/27/unitofwork-action-filter-for-asp-net-mvc-and-nhibernate.aspx then this won't help me, because I have situations where more than one action is executed within a web request. So the 2nd action would use a disposed session. If I am wrong or there are other ways let me know.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, use a regex to look at the Request.Url to match on file extensions you don't want to process and return without processing.

Comment: This sounds good :) But I thought I could configure an HttpModule in IIS/web.config.

Comment: A module doesn't allow you to define a matching pattern in web.config.  A IHttpHandler DOES allow you to define a pattern, maybe that would work better in your situation?

Comment: The only thing I would add is that you should look at path rather than URL, since you may end up not creating a session for something like http://mydomain.com/image/get?format=.jpg or something similar, or you may end up with a pretty complicated regex expression